# Delete yeshiva-policies tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Should we delete the [yeshiva-policies](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yeshiva-policies) tag?

I suspect that it will encourage off-topic questions, as the focus is on Jewish institutions rather than Judaism.

The [only question which has it](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78956/why-do-kollelim-have-only-half-a-day-on-fast-days), seems off topic to me.

One can disagree with the latter claim, but agree to the proposal that the tag be removed.

Comment: Who voted to close this as primarily opinion based? Meta is *designed* for opinion questions.

Answer (score 3):

While I disagree entirely with your scope-based argument, I went ahead and removed the tag from the lone question that initiated it. We already have [yeshiva-school](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yeshiva-school), which itself only applies to a few dozen questions, so it seems to me that that ought to be sufficiently specific for questions of this nature. Editing out a brand-new tag from a brand-new question, leaving behind a set of tags that fits better within the tremendous menu of tags we already have, is a minor edit, so I just did it.

Comment: May be an equivalent of the hebrew עולם הישיבות as "yeshiva world". I think that to know the yeshiva world is important. And questions on yeshivot and collelim, e.g. lituanian or chassidic tendencies, shitot in musar, limud, are very valuable.

Comment: @kouty, like I said, there are existing tags under which such content would fit, including [tag:yeshiva-school].

Comment: ok.............